# What is the exact Hamiltonian core of the Fragment Molecular Orbital Method?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry

My major is not chemistry and I am trying to understand the Hamiltonian core of the [Fragment Molecular Orbital (FMO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_molecular_orbital) method.

I think it should be the normal Hamiltonian core of the restricted Hartree-Fock plus two other terms: nuclei attraction between other fragments and the current fragment in the calculation and also the potential energy between them.

But I was wondering If I could get the formula, as I saw in different papers that there are different versions and different formulae associated with that.

Comment: I must wonder whether this would be better suited at [mattermodeling.se]. *Please refrain from asking it there _again_.* If you would like it migrated there, please raise a custom flag and a moderator will take care of this. To make this clear though: I do not think it is off topic here, so there is no urgent need for migation.